# Java problem time limit exceeded issue

Tags: java, algorithm, execution-time

Im coding a problem(reference --http://www.codechef.com/FEB11/problems/THREECLR/)

The below is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

 static String ReadLn (int maxLg)  // utility function to read from stdin
    {
        byte lin[] = new byte [maxLg];
        int lg = 0, car = -1;
        String line = "";

        try
        {
            while (lg < maxLg)
            {
                car = System.in.read();
                if ((car < 0) || (car == '\n')) break;
                lin [lg++] += car;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return (null);
        }

        if ((car < 0) && (lg == 0)) return (null);  // eof
        return (new String (lin, 0, lg));
    }

 public static boolean iscontains(HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> resultmap,HashSet<Integer> b, int index)
 {
     boolean result=false;
     for(Iterator<Integer> iter = b.iterator();iter.hasNext();)
        {  int tmp=Integer.valueOf(iter.next().toString());
            if(resultmap.get(index).contains(tmp))
                    result=true;                
        }

     return result;
 }


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
    try {

    HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> pairlist = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>();
     String input=null;
     StringTokenizer idata;
     int tc=0;
    input=Main.ReadLn(255);
    tc=Integer.parseInt(input);
    while(--tc>=0)
    {
        input=Main.ReadLn(255);
        idata = new StringTokenizer (input);idata = new StringTokenizer (input);
        int dishnum= Integer.parseInt(idata.nextToken());
        int pairnum= Integer.parseInt(idata.nextToken());
        while (--pairnum>=0)
        {
            input=Main.ReadLn(255);
            idata = new StringTokenizer (input);idata = new StringTokenizer (input);
            int dish1=Integer.parseInt(idata.nextToken());
            int dish2=Integer.parseInt(idata.nextToken());
            if(pairlist.containsKey((Integer)dish1))
            {
                HashSet<Integer> dishes=new HashSet<Integer>();
                dishes=pairlist.get(dish1);
                dishes.add(dish2);
                pairlist.put(dish1, dishes);
            }
            else
            {
                HashSet<Integer> dishes=new HashSet<Integer>();
                dishes.add(dish2);
                pairlist.put(dish1, dishes);
            }
        }
        int maxrounds=1;
        HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> resultlist = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>();
        HashSet<Integer> addresult=new HashSet<Integer>();
        addresult.add(1);
        resultlist.put(1,addresult);
        System.out.print("1");
        for(int i=2;i<=dishnum;i++)
        {
            boolean found_one=false;
            boolean second_check=false;
            int minroundnum=maxrounds;
            boolean pairlistcontains=false;
            pairlistcontains=pairlist.containsKey(i);
            for(int j=maxrounds;j>=1;j--)
            {
                if(!found_one){
                if(pairlistcontains)
                {
                    if(!iscontains(resultlist,pairlist.get((Integer) i),j))
                    {
                         for(Iterator<Integer> resultiter = resultlist.get(j).iterator();resultiter.hasNext();)
                         {
                             if(pairlist.get(resultiter.next()).contains(i))
                                 second_check=true;  
                         }
                         if(second_check==false)
                         {
                             found_one=true;
                             minroundnum=j;
                             j=0;
                             //second_check=false;
                         }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                     for(Iterator<Integer> resultiter = resultlist.get(j).iterator();resultiter.hasNext();)
                     {
                         if(pairlist.get(resultiter.next()).contains(i))
                             second_check=true;  
                     }
                     if(second_check==false)
                     {
                         found_one=true;
                         minroundnum=j;
                         j=0;
                         //second_check=false;
                     }

                }
                second_check=false;


            }
        }
            if((minroundnum==maxrounds)&&(found_one==false))
                {
                ++minroundnum;
                ++maxrounds;
                }
            else
            {
                found_one=false;
            }
            HashSet<Integer> add2list=new HashSet<Integer> ();
            if(resultlist.containsKey(minroundnum))
            {
                add2list=resultlist.get(minroundnum);
                add2list.add(i);
            }
            else
            {
                add2list.add(i);
            }
            resultlist.put(minroundnum,add2list);
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(minroundnum);


        }
        if((tc !=-1))
            System.out.println();

    }


    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}
}}
```

I have checked this code on online judges like Ideone and have been getting the desired results. But when i submit this code, I get a Time Limit exceeded error. I have tested this code on Ideone with a sufficiently large set of input and the time taken to execute was lesser than 1 second. It seems to have a bug or a memory leak that seems to have drained all the happiness from my life.
Any pointers/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT1 --

Thanks for the replies guys, I ran the code with the input generated by the following python script --

```
import random
filename="input.txt"
file=open(filename,'w')
file.write("50")
file.write("\n")
for i in range(0,50):
        file.write("500 10000")
        file.write("\n")
        for j in range(0,10000):
                file.write(str(random.randrange(1,501))+" "+str(random.randrange(1,501)))
                file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

And my code took a whopping 71052 milliseconds to execute on the input provided by the above script. I have to now get down the execution time to 8000 milliseconds to the very least.
Im working on trying out replacing the HashMaps and the HashSets as suggested by rfeak and am also wondering if memoization would help in this scenario. Please advise.

EDIT2 --
Recoding my algo using arrays seems to have worked. Only just though, resubmitting the same code at different times gives me Accepted Solution and Time limit exceeded :D I have though of another way to use hashmaps to optimize a little further.
Thanks a load for the help guys !

Comment: have you considered that they are feeding it a much larger input and your code takes too long to process it?

Comment: Do you know how big the dataset they are submitting is?  Can you get ahold of that data set?

Comment: My guess is you are expecting an input which does not happen or there is an input which causes your program to go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind the code and what its complexity is? Have you tried submitting the code without the `try/catch` lines? You should never submit code with error checking to an online judge. This will only slow your program down, and a respectable judge will never feed you bad data.

Comment: A try/catch block is for free when no exception gets caught, isn't it. He makes no error checking, he makes (sort of) exception swallowing.

Comment: @IVlad -- Thanks for the suggestion. removing exception checking did not help though. The basic idea behind the code is that i store in a hashmap all the dished that are linked as provided in the input and by default i assign the first dish round 1 and maintain a hashmap<Integer,Arraylist> for the result as well denoting which all dishes come in which round(the round is the key to the hashmap). Now for each dish i iterate through the hashmap form the highest round value checking for the following 2 conditions -- Conditions follow in next comment

Comment: @IVlad -- The 2 conditions that the round must meet for he dish under consideration to fall in that round is -- 
Condition1 -- This round does not have any dishes(already in it) that are present in the first hashmap(wherein i store the mapping between dish and arraylist of linked dishes) value for the key being this particular dish.
Condition 2--
The dishes already present in this round must not have the dish under consideration in their arraylist of linked dishes, stored in the hashmap mentioned in condtion 1. 
Makes sense ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How much memory does your program use when you run locally?

If they are running your Java program without enough memory, you could be spending a lot of time trying to garbage collect. This could destroy your 1 second time.

If you need to save time and memory (To be determined ...), I have 2 suggetions.

Replace `HashSet<Integer>` with `BitSet`. Similar interface, much faster implementation, and uses much less memory. Especially with the numbers I see in the problem.

Replace `Map<Integer,X>` with an `X[]` - The Integer key can simply be an int (primitive) index into your array. Again, faster and smaller.

Comment: Definitely get rid of the `HashSet` and `Map`. The numbers given in the problem are all small enough for an array (or `BitSet` might be even faster than that, but I don't think you need it here) to be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Im not very clear on the BitSet implementation. JavaDoc says they contain the bit representation of a number and support logical operations on them. I would not primarily want to be doing that kind of manipulation on the input data but would definitely try that out if it is the most practical and best approach. Please advise.

Comment: @JCoder - Ignore how it describes it's internal representation. It's best to think about a BitSet as a Set of int (primitives). The set either contains an integer, or it doesn't. To see if it does, call BitSet.get(someInt). To put an integer into the set call BitSet.set(someInt). In this way it behaves exactly as a Set<Integer>. ... Now, if you're really interested in why it's smaller than a Set<Integer>, I can add to my answer.